# Mysql request for column content sum

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, request, sum

I am working on Joomla for a new website.
I would like to show the total number of hits for all entries of a component.
For instance, the table name in mysql is `'cars'`, and the column name `'hits'`.

I tried to put several request I found on the web (i paste the code in the module Flexi Content), but nothing shows up.

The module shows in front : `"There are currently xx cars on the website"`.

Can someone tell me what is the right requests?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you us show some code?

Comment: Mysql query should be 'SELECT SUM(hits) FROM cars' but if you want more detailed info how to implement it, you will have to share some of yours code.